# Fixing "Use of undeclared identifier 'NSPreferencePanesDirectory'"

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

My application uses the [following code](http://cl.ly/1I3d3O2P3L1B122X1c15):

```
#if MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_5 < MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
    NSArray *globalPreferencePanes = 
        NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSPreferencePanesDirectory,
            NSAllDomainsMask, YES);        
#else
    NSArray *globalPreferencePanes = 
        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"/Library/PreferencePanes", 
            [@"~/Library/PreferencePanes" stringByExpandingTildeInPath], nil];
#endif
return globalPreferencePanes;
```

The project under which I'm compiling this is aimed at the 10.5 Mac OSX SDK, where `NSPreferencePanesDirectory` does not exist (it only exists in 10.6+). Because of this, I have the `#if` and `#else` in order to check what version of Mac OSX we're running under, so I know whether I should use the `NSPreferencePanesDirectory` or just manually give the location of the preference pane directories.

What should I change in order to stop getting this "use of undeclared identifier" error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#if` is evaluated at compile time, not run time. What you probably want to do is use the current SDK (10.7), and do something like this:

```
NSArray *globalPreferencePanes;

if (NSAppKitVersionNumber >= NSAppKitVersionNumber10_6)
    globalPreferencePanes = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSPreferencePanesDirectory, NSAllDomainsMask, YES);        
else
    globalPreferencePanes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"/Library/PreferencePanes", [@"~/Library/PreferencePanes" stringByExpandingTildeInPath], nil];

    return globalPreferencePanes;
```

Making sure to set your target OS version to 10.5 so the symbol is weak linked. Otherwise, you could drop down and use CoreServices' `FSFindFolder()`:

```
NSMutableArray *globalPreferencePanes = [NSMutableArray array];
FSRef foundRef;

OSErr err = FSFindFolder(kLocalDomain, kPreferencePanesFolderType, false, &foundRef);

if (err != noErr) {
    CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateFromFSRef(NULL, &fsRef);
    CFStringRef path = CFURLCopyPath(url);
    [globalPreferencePanes addObject:(id)path];
    CFRelease(path);
    CFRelease(url);
}

OSErr err = FSFindFolder(kUserDomain, kPreferencePanesFolderType, false, &foundRef);

if (err != noErr) {
    CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateFromFSRef(NULL, &fsRef);
    CFStringRef path = CFURLCopyPath(url);
    [globalPreferencePanes addObject:(id)path];
    CFRelease(path);
    CFRelease(url);
}

return globalPreferencePanes;
```

(Not tested)

Comment: This wasn't the 100% solution, please see my answer below if this solution did not perfectly work for you. My code is still only a slight modification of Wevah's code. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 10.5.x you will still get an error since "NSPreferencePanesDirectory" is not a known symbol. I solved this issue for a friend and changed the FindPrefsDir function code in osxsupport.m to:

```
char *FindPrefsDir(void)
{
    char *resstr = NULL;
    NSArray *globalPreferencePanes;

    globalPreferencePanes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"/Library/PreferencePanes", [@"~/Library/PreferencePanes" stringByExpandingTildeInPath], nil];

    if ([globalPreferencePanes count] > 0)
    {
        resstr = StringToChar([globalPreferencePanes objectAtIndex:0]) ;
    }
    return resstr;

}
```

Thanks to Wevah for his code suggestion, but it didn't directly work for me. So I changed it a little bit and my friend who is still on 10.5.x could perfectly build it after that.